# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker - How to get my date into a post formular?

Tags: php, post, datepicker

I used Datepicker a few times and always transmitted data with GET.
Now I'm trying to use it with POST.
Here is my HTML CODE:

```
<div class="input-group date" name="eintritt" id="datetimepicker_benutzer_detail_start">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
 $(function () {
$('#datetimepicker_benutzer_detail_start').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: '2018/01/01',
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        locale: 'de'
});
```

Now my question:
There is a formular with some text fields and those are sent via POST and stored in a MYSQL table.
But how is it possible to get the shown date from the Datepicker? It's not possible with $_POST['eintritt']...

My form tag looks like this:

```
<form id="benutzer_daten" name="benutzer_daten" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
```

And the I just get the POST values like this:

```
$vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
$nachname = $_POST['nachname'];
```

And after there is a normal mysql insert...

Comment: There are missing pieces you need to add to your post: form tag and the php code where you save the data.

Comment: I added the informations, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is assign a name tag to the input. This is how input gets linked with the php $_POST. So, in your case:

```
<input type="text" name="vorname" class="form-control" />
```

will be assigned to

```
$vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
```

Also, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/9618184) if you are not preventing MySQL injections.

Comment: Thanks, yes but my problem is the input field from datepicker, all other fields are submitted without any problem. This field is not submitting the information. I think there should be a code to write the date while choosing into the value="" field.

Comment: I don't understand you completely, but change `vorname` with something else that matches a datetimepicker field name, like `name="datetime"` and use it in PHP like `$_POST['datetime']`

Comment: Ouu now I saw my mistake, the name field was in the wrong tag (not in the input tag). Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you!